# Table SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I created a table to store the results of my sql query.
My goal is to display the first line of the table and when I click on a button it shows me the following line:

```
$questions = array();
   $resultat = $pdo -> query("SELECT question, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4 FROM proposition");
    while($row=$resultat -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $questions[] = array($row['question'], $row['rep1'], $row['rep2'], 
        $row['rep3'], $row['rep4']);
      }
     foreach($questions as $cle1 => $valeur1)
   {
      echo "personne n°:" . $cle1 . "<br />";

     foreach ($valeur1 as $cle2=>$valeur2)

       {
        echo "Clé : ".$cle2 .", Valeur: " . $valeur2 . "<br />\n";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, What did you already try? Your question is quite broad at the moment, maybe you can specify what is not working or where you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome! It sounds like you have a project, you have a table, and you have a script. But what is the actual problem? Where are you stuck, what is the misbehavior you see, and what is your question to us (apart from "please finish my project").